# What is wrong with this LINQ code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, vb.net-2010

First, I have function to flatten all controls on a `Control`:

```
Protected Function GetAllControls(Optional ownerControl As Control = Nothing) As IEnumerable(Of Control)

    Dim ret = New List(Of Control)()
    For Each child As Control In If(ownerControl, Me).Controls
        ret.AddRange(GetAllControls(child))
    Next
    ret.Add(ownerControl)
    Return ret

End Function
```

Then, I want to hide certain buttons on a control using this code:

```
Dim buttons = GetAllControls().Where(Function(c) c.Name.StartsWith("subButton"))
For Each ctrl As Control In buttons
    ctrl.Visible = False
    Debug.WriteLine("Hid button " & ctrl.Name)
Next
```

Yet, after four buttons - the correct count - have been hidden, I get a `NullReferenceException`, with VS2012 highlighting the lambda expression.

What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in your first function adds `ownerControl`, which is null the first time you call it, so its adding a Nothing to the list. In your lambda you're doing a `c.Name` which will throw an exception when `c` is Nothing.

Comment: Thank you! That would have taken me a while, looking in wrong places etc.